# Error while using Replace function of String

Tags: c#

```
Str.replace(',','','');
```

I have to replace `(,)` with `(',')`

but in replace function we have to pass character in `' '` so it is giving me an error.

Comment: No, you can pass in strings just fine.

Comment: A constant enclosed in double quotes `"` is a `string`. A constant enclosed in single quotes `'` is a `char` and can contain only one character.

Answer (score 2):

[String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Replace%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has 2 overloads, one accepts `char` and one accepts `string` so you can do this:

```
var value = existing.Replace(",", "','");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ensure your values are quoted properly:

```
String myString = "test, A";
myString.Replace(",", "','");
```

Answer (score 1):

`','` is clearly more than one character. So you can't use [`String.Replace(Char, Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx) overload.

You can use [`String.Replace(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) overload instead.

```
string s = ",,";
Console.WriteLine(s.Replace(",", "','"));
```

Output will be;

```
','','
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/aXpQKW).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass characters in '' (as characters), you can also pass them as strings using "".  That should solve your problem.

```
Str.Replace(",", "','");
```